# UINavigation controller array bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I was just wondering about a bug I came across when popping my UINavigationController. Whatever UIViewController I am currently in, I have implemented a logout controller that pops back to the root controller in my UINavigationController. The main code that does this is listed here.

```
NSLog(@"Root Controller: %@", [[self.navigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0] class]);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Root Controller: %@", [[self.navigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0] class]);
```

This is what the console displays.

```
Root Controller: DetailViewController
Root Controller: (null)
```

However when I change the above code to:

```
NSLog(@"Root Controller: %@", [[self.navigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0] class]);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Root Controller: %@", [[self.navigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0] class]);
```

The results in the console is displayed as:

```
Root Controller: DetailViewController
Root Controller: DetailViewController
```

It was bothering me for a while why when I popped the UINavigationController to the DetailViewController that it didnt fire the ViewWillAppear method to update my login information. It seems to me that when I pop to the 0 index it is accessing an array object that is out of bounds but when I pop to index 1, thats where the current root controller is. Does anyone know what the cause of this would be?

Comment: Just suggesting, to pop a navigation stack till its root view controller there's an easier method [UINavigationController popToRootViewController].

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `self.navigationController` is being set to nil after `self` is popped off the stack.

If that's the case, it looks like popping to the view controller at index 1 does not reset `self.navigationController` to nil (either because `self` is the view controller at index 1 or some call in viewWill|Did?Appear is setting it again).

Comment: Ahh thats why. The current view controller is at index 1. That explains it. Thanks.

Comment: If that answers your question, feel free to click the checkmark to mark it answered.